# How to reference childs of some JPA inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

Assume we have simple hierarchy Vehicle with children Car, Train, Bus etc. How can one reference the proper vehicle based on used inheritance type. For SINGLE_TABLE it looks easy you have one id you can reference in let's say Driver entity(table), the same for JOINED. But how can you achieve that with TABLE_PER_CLASS is it possible at all?

If Driver defines `private Vehicle vehicle` can I just type cast it to proper entity type. I guess it is not possible to do with TABLE_PER_CLASS as there is no discriminator.

Comment: Whether you use one strategy or the other doesn't change anything on how associations are handled. If you want a ManyToOne association with a driver, you add a field of type Car to your entity, and annotate it with ManyToOne. And if you have an association to a Vahicle, and that Vehicle happens to be a Car, then calling its polymorphic methods will call the Car methods. Don't cast, as Hibernate uses proxies.

Comment: How will JPA find out the proper table in TABLE_PER_CLASS as every table has it's own ID generator?

Comment: No, every table shouldn't have its own ID generator. Since Car and Trains are all instances of Vehicle, a Vehicle ID must uniquely identify a vehicle, and you thus can't have a Car and a Train with the same ID.

Comment: So it means that when I have used `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)` on parent entity class. The JPA knows you have inheritance and will reuse the proper sequence column for all child entities?

Comment: Yes. The strategy is used to generate IDs of Vehicle entity instances. Car and Train are Vehicle entity instances.

Comment: It will join the tables and select the proper id. What about the type casting?

Comment: Don't use type-casting. Use polymorphism. The visitor pattern can help. Hibernate uses proxies, so if a driver has an association to a Vehicle, since Hibernate can't know in advance what the concrete type of the Vehicle is (whatever the inheritance strategy is), it uses a Proxy, which lazily loads and wraps the appropriate Vehicle subclass instance, but is neither a Car, nor a Train, nor a Bus.